# What libraries can I use to make tiny Windows programs?

Tags: c++, windows, unix, libraries

Perhaps some of you people have heard of http://suckless.org/ and their set of Unix tools. Basically, they're a set of programs that each aim to do one thing but do it well, while still being as simple and resource-light as possible.

I've been trying to find a way to reproduce this style of programming on Windows with C++ but all the libraries I know of would produce binaries that are huge with respect to their function. Even the simplest of anything Qt, for example, is generally several megabytes large. I'm not against packaging dependencies along with distributables but I wouldn't want to do it to that level.

Binary size is not one of my main goals but simplicity is and big libraries like these are, by construction, not simple. If binary size were your primary concern you could use runtime compression just like kkreiger or malware.

A possibility would be to go commando and use only ISO Standard C++ libraries but rebuilding a sockets or networking system for a small single-purpose application is not really something anyone would want to be troubled with.

For some reason I thought there was some general-purpouse library that Windows developers could count on everyone and their grandma having readily accessible but now I don't know if anything like that exists. What can you use to write code that adheres to the Unix Philosophy but for Windows targets?

Comment: Erm, the Win32 API? You can't get much lower level than that...

Comment: What! How did I forget about the existence of the Windows API. There is also MFC. Transfer it to an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should target the Win32 API directly. You can't get much lower level than that. In the Windows world, everything directly or indirectly wraps the SDK functions, including the so-called "standard C++ libraries".

Alternatively, you could use something like MFC or WTL, which are relatively thin C++ wrappers over the Win32 API. Because of the overhead of the class libraries, such programs will be slightly smaller than those created using only the SDK, but nowadays, the actual overhead is completely insignificant.

The desires expressed in your question are *precisely* why I learned and still use the Win32 API today, so that's definitely what I would go with. Plus, your programs will look and feel native, which is way better than the crap most "cross-platform GUI toolkits" put out. The advantages of this can't be underestimated.

But if you just open up Visual Studio and compile a simple little SDK "Hello World" app, it'll still be awfully large. Kilobytes, to be sure, but that still seems like a lot for about the simplest app imaginable. If you really need to cut things down further, you can try telling Visual Studio not to link to the C runtime libraries and define your own `main` entrypoint. This does mean that you'll have to implement all of your own startup initialization code, but this can reduce the size of a trivial app substantially.

Matt Pietrek [had this same idea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb985746.aspx) some years ago, although you'll probably want to take time to "modernize" his original code significantly if you decide to go this route.

Comment: I think you meant to say, "slightly larger" instead of "slightly smaller" in the second paragraph of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) is a popular cross platform minimal gui toolkit.

Or a popular alternative if you don't need too much detailed interaction is just to fire up a minimal embedded webserver and do all the 'gui' in html in a browser.